# How high could I set my maximum session length?

Tags: php, apache, session, ubuntu

I run a website which has a quote process: results, customer details, payment.

The nature of our business means customers want to compare us to other websites. I've noticed from the server logs that users can leave a mid quote process tab open for up to 24 hours, then choose to continue purchasing through us.

The problem is our website uses sessions to log the order progress. These sessions are expiring meaning the customer/server is losing it's link.

I spoke to my host and we upped the session.gc_maxlifetime  to 7200 - or 2 hours.

I get an email alert every time a user gets a session timed out error on the site and we still get a few a day from users with tabs open for way past 2 hours. We offer a friendly message asking the user to restart their quote, but I bet it puts some of them off.

Could we realistically up the maxlifetime to be 24 hours? And see if that helps bring the number of users hitting this problem down?

Our business is still quite small and is getting less than 500 quotes a day - so surely our server would be able to handle this?

I'd just like anyone's opinion if this is a NO NO smaxlifetime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the only problem you could have to cope with is the lack of **storage**:

Let's say one of your session file is usually ~1 MB and you have ~500 visitors (sessions created) per day.
Then, you'll need at least 500 MB of storage reserved for sessions.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime), php.net says:

`session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up.`

Comment: We are going to up it to 86400 seconds (24 hours) and see what happens next! With 7gb of space it shouldn't be an issue. Thanks the the idea.